# Does it make sense to use reflection when implementing toString()?

Tags: java, json, reflection, orm, gson

```
@Override 
public String toString() { 
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
```

Am I breaking some good practice, *"Joshua"-pattern* thing, general design pattern or other convention by simply doing this as default behavior for my model objects?

`toString()` will anyhow only be used in debugging in the paradigm (Android) that we are currently using. That's also the reason why I like seeing the object in JSON since much ORM/json persistence will be happening through http->php/python->mysql and to the local SQLite.

Comment: You're not breaking anything. `toString()` can return any String (but it should probably return the same String every time you call it on the same instance, unless the internal state of the instance changes).

Comment: yes, that is the prerequesite if believed to be ... the only one(?) for toString(). In requirement of convention that is

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: not if the internal state of the instance changes.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I should put that in words (ie. plagiarize your comment).

Comment: Internal state? I mean of course that the json output will be the actual object, whatever state it is currently in, but in json. Gson will do this - if im not mistaken

Comment: @tortal I was talking in general. Of course, Gson will do this.

Comment: There are quite a few possible issues to watch for - expensive load-on-demand collections (performance), bi-directional references (endless loop), root object of huge object tree  (whole database in the debug statement) and so on. That is the reason that in general case I do not do generic & reflection based toString(). Not sure if any such scenario applies here though.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes. It's OK to use GSON/Jackson/Reflections library to implement toString() method.

There are few ways to implement toString method.

1. Reflections (Apache library)

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString(){
       return org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
   }
   ```
2. JSON based implementation (GSON, Jackson libraries)

   ```
   // GSON library for JSON
   @Override
   public String toString(){
       return new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(this);
   }

   // Jackson libabry for JSON/YAML
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       try {
           return new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(this);
       } catch (com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
3. ToStringBuilder (available with apache-commons library)

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return new org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder(this).
           append("field1", field1).
           append("field2", field2).
           toString();
   }
   ```
4. Hard-core toString() implementation

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return new StringBuilder()
           .append("field1:"+field1)
           .append("field2:"+field2)
           .toString();
   }
   ```
5. Lombok annotations : Generates toString() at compile time

   ```
   import lombok.ToString;

   @ToString
   public class ToStringExample {}
   ```

Comment: Amazing answer, very detailed with several options and in few lines. This should be the accepted one.

Comment: The answer could be improved by discussing the contract of [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) and whether a JSON serialization meets that contract (I think it does) and any potential downsides (performance? but mitigated by the contract - the method is for debugging / display, so not expected to be performant)

Comment: Yes I was wondering about performance of using Jackson versus just plain reflection for printing the state of an object. Using Jackson seems like overkill to just print out an object. Code is also much cleaner in option 1.

Answer (score 12):

There's no harm in doing it this way. I would suggest you to create a static variable for your `Gson` instance and enable pretty printing:

```
static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

This way the output from `toString` method will be formatted.

Comment: Why new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting(). Why not just "new Gson()"?

Comment: i got it after some googling. Should have done that first. Using pretty printing will be quite useful

Comment: I guess `toJson(obj)` you were meant to indicate. `toString()` won't print out anything usefule.

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: If you use that GSon pretty printing in your toString() method it is going to look like garbage in your debugger because it will be full of newlines.

(Sorry didn't have enough rep to comment above)

Comment: Not sure which debugger you had in mind but IntelliJ and probably other IDEs will cope fine with newlines in `toString()` output.

Comment: Many years later I realize this guy actually had a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad for performance because Gson uses introspection to figure out which fields to print.

Apart from that, I think it's ok. That's not the standard Java toString implementation but I don't think changing it would be an anti-pattern.

Comment: Your answer offers no evidence or arguments other than "I think", which isn't very useful :-(

Comment: @tdraun yes, introspection has a high cost, so you are correct, as well the other consideration. That Rich guy just said naive conjectures, aka BS.

Comment: I agree, your answer is fine actually. There is no reason to bash your answer because you included the words "I think".