# Return Json from toStringMethod with single quotes in Java?

Tags: java, json, tostring

I want my toString method to return the object in json format with single quotes. I don't want to manage the toString method manually. Is there a way to do it automatically? Intent is , In case I add a new variable, I don't want to redo my toString method.

class MyClass {
int myVariable;

```
    @Overide
    public string toString() {
       return "'MyClass':{'myVariable'" +myVariable+"':}"
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you _want_ single quotes? Or JSON from `toString` at all?

Comment: You can use `lombok` to implement `@ToString` so you dont need to write it yourself - https://www.projectlombok.org/features/ToString

Answer (score 4):

you can use a library like Jackson or Gson,

Example:

With Jackson:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

With Gson:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
```

Example output:

```
{"calle":"Calle","numero":100}
```

you have examples here: [Does it make sense to use reflection when implementing toString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527932/does-it-make-sense-to-use-reflection-when-implementing-tostring)

Comment: Thankyou, is there a way to print it in single quotes? I want my variable and value to be in single quotes

Comment: you can add replace to the output something like this: `return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this).replace("\"", "'");` this will generate the json like this: _{'street':'Street','number':100}_

Comment: Also, putting a ObjectMapper as a dependency of a model class is usually frowned upon

Answer (score 0):

You could create a utility class like this (note: single quoted JSON is not valid but if that's what you want):

```
public final class JsonBuilder {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    static {
        //OBJECT_MAPPER.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        OBJECT_MAPPER.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
    }

    public static <T> String toJson(final T obj) {
        if (null == obj) {
            return null;
        }
        Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = OBJECT_MAPPER.writerFor(cls);
        try {
            return "'" + cls.getName() + "':" + objectWriter.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and then your `toString()` method:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return JsonBuilder.toJson(this);
    }
```

this will output:
`'MyClass':{'myVariable':0}`

if you want indented output just uncomment the ObjectMapper configuration with `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT`